Unable to import ServiceA present in repoA inside ServiceB in repoB while writing a test case in angular and jest framework
I have a scenario where I have an angular service ServiceA inside repo RepoA. In the index.ts of RepoA, I have export * as ServiceA from './serviceA'. ServiceA has the annotation
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root', })
Next, in repoB, I have another angular service ServiceB that depends on ServiceA. ServiceB also has the decorator
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root', }).
While trying to run a test using jest and TestBed it fails with the error
Error: NG0202: This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 2 of the parameter list is invalid.
This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.

Please check that 1) the type for the parameter at index 2 is correct and 2) the correct Angular decorators are defined for this class and its ancestors.

Any idea what might be a fix to this issue ?

In my case, I was using the follow
"test": {
           "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
           "options": {
             "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
             "polyfills": [
               "zone.js",
               "zone.js/testing"
             ]
           }
         }

and using ng test command to run the tests which internally used jest. I removed the test configuration from angular.json and directly used the jest command with the following configuration for jest.config.ts & jest.setup.ts and everything worked flawlessly for me.
import type { Config } from 'jest'
import defaultTransformerOptions from 'jest-preset-angular/presets'

const esModules = ['.*uuid']

const jestConfig: Config = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.ts'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  verbose: true,
  globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/projects/**/*.spec.ts'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!.+\\.mjs$|${esModules.join('|')})`],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(mjs)$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js)$': [
      'jest-preset-angular',
      {
        ...defaultTransformerOptions,
        stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
      },
    ],
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'mjs', 'json', 'node'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['perf-.+\\.spec\\.ts'],
}

export default jestConfig


import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from 'node:util'
import 'zone.js'; // Required for Angular
import 'zone.js/testing'; // Required for Angular's fakeAsync utilities
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Required to init once before using TestBed in all test cases
TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
)

if (!global.TextEncoder) {
    global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
}
if (!global.TextDecoder) {
    // @ts-ignore
    global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
}


Hope it helps.
